# jQuery Delete confirmation in foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, loops

I'm trying to make a delete confirmation with Twitter bootsrap in a foreach loop. My code works, but every time, it deletes the first record in the table(the id passing is not working correctly). Could you please help. 
**Here is my code**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    @foreach ($employees as $key => $employee)
    <!-- twitter bootstrap delete confrimation -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteModal">Confirm Remove</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>You are about to remove a team member.</p>
            <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-times"></i>Cancel</button>
            {!! Form::open(['route' => ['employees.destroy', $employee->id], 'method' => 'DELETE', 'style' => 'display: inline-block']) !!}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash-o"></i>Remove</button>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ (($employees->currentPage() - 1 ) * $employees->perPage() ) + $key + 1 }}</th>
      <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $employee->email }}</td>
      <td>{{ $employee->position->name }}</td>
      <td class="position-btn-in-the-right input-prepend">
        <a href="{{ route('employees.show', $employee->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-eye"></i>View</a> 
        <a href="{{ route('employees.edit', $employee->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</i></a>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-href="{{ route('employees.destroy', $employee->id) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash-o"></i>Remove</button>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

**And my js:**

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(this)(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete[]" .....>

Comment: that way it doesn't open the confirmation window. the button doesn't do anything

Comment: try change it to js to #confirm-delete[]

Comment: WHat is the purpose of this `$(this)(e.relatedTarget)`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was getting the same problem before , you are setting a model component with a static id wich will be repeated inside the @foreach , so for that you have to set a dynamic id for that component , try something like

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete<?= $employee->id ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
```

so when the DOM load it will create a lot of modal component with such a different ids 
and for the button you can just put this with no JS required

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-href="{{ route('employees.destroy', $employee->id) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete<?= $employee->id ?>"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash-o"></i>Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$(this)(e.relatedTarget)
```

is wrong. Even if you change it to:

```
$(e.relatedTarget)
```

It's not valid.

So, because you are looking for the button clicked to show your modal, you may use:

```
   $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
      if ($(document.activeElement).is('button.btn.btn-sm.btn-danger')) {
            $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(document.activeElement).data('href'));
      }
   });
```

> The [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement): Returns the currently focused element, that is, the element that will get keystroke events if the user types any. This attribute is read only.

In other words, when you click on the button, document.activeElement  is exactly the clicked button.

My example:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if ($(document.activeElement).is('button.btn.btn-sm.btn-danger')) {
      $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(document.activeElement).data('href'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th></th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <!-- twitter bootstrap delete confrimation -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModal"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteModal">Confirm Remove</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>You are about to remove a team member.</p>

                    <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>

                    <p class="debug-url"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash-o"></i>Remove
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <tr>
        <th>{{ (($employees->currentPage() - 1 ) * $employees->perPage() ) + $key + 1 }}</th>
        <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $employee->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $employee->position->name }}</td>
        <td class="position-btn-in-the-right input-prepend">
            <a href="{{ route('employees.show', $employee->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i
                    class="fa fa-btn fa-eye"></i>View</a>
            <a href="{{ route('employees.edit', $employee->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i
                    class="fa fa-btn fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</i></a>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-href="{{ route('employees.destroy', $employee->id) }}"
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash-o"></i>Remove
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>{{ (($employees->currentPage() - 1 ) * $employees->perPage() ) + $key + 1 }}</th>
        <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $employee->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $employee->position->name }}</td>
        <td class="position-btn-in-the-right input-prepend">
            <a href="{{ route('employees.show', $employee->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i
                    class="fa fa-btn fa-eye"></i>View</a>
            <a href="{{ route('employees.edit', $employee->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i
                    class="fa fa-btn fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</i></a>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-href="{{ route('employees.destroy', $employee->id) }}"
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash-o"></i>Remove
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```